# SuperSearch not searching Playa field

Tags: playa, solspace, search, supersearch

I have a supersearch tag that is searching through my channel which includes a playa field.

This is my tag:

```
{exp:super_search:results
    channel="articles"
    limit="3"
    search_in="title|speakers"
}
```

The speakers tag is a Playa field (containing just a first_name and last_name) and the title.

It appears that my playa field is not being search, even though I have it set to searchable in the channel_field settings.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What version of EE, Super Search and Playa are you using? Have you checked that the keyword you're using for your search is present in the exp_channel_data table in the column corresponding to your Playa field? Also, did you try clearing Super Search cache (Preferences) and rebuilding the lexicon (Utilities)?

Comment: @solspace I'm running EE v2.7.3, Playa v4.4.5, and Super Search v2.0.

I tried clearing both the cache and rebuilding the lexicon, and yes. The term (in this case the speaker's name) is in the exp_channel_data table.